# Streaming API encryption?

Tags: encryption, streaming-api

Concerning Streaming API in Salesforce : are the messages send, via streaming API , encrypted in any way?

On the ComedD website, they mention the measures to take concerning Security : https://docs.cometd.org/current/reference/#_security but are any of these measures standard implemented? like encrytion via TLS for instance?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is any specific native encryption beyond [recommending the use of HTTPS](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_streaming.meta/api_streaming/https.htm). I'd use stronger wording and say that you must use HTTPS for the Streaming API.

It also uses the [standard cookie with the server](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_streaming.meta/api_streaming/intro_client_specs.htm) and a HTTP header for the SessionID / OAuth access token.